# Powershell 'Get-StoredCredential'

Tags: powershell

I have a Stored Credential that I have saved in Powershell using the 'New-StoredCredential' command. The script I have written requires to be run as a different user and when done so cannot access the previous stored credential. I know it's saved because I can run a normal instance of Powershell and query a targeted stored credential. Any ideas to get this to work? I would like to avoid having to export the credentials into a '.cred' file.

Comment: The whole idea of the credentials manager is that the credentials are encrypted with the windows user's password and therefore can only be restored by somebody authenticated by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour, you cannot store credentials and allow other people access to them, this would work for you, as you can decrypt your own credentials.  You can't decrypt them on another machine, let alone another user.

If someone needs access to do whatever the script is doing, your best option is to give them access to that, rather that try to hijack some credentials from someone that can.

Comment: Makes sense, the 'other' person is my self. I have another account I use to access a certain server which the script calls to be run as that user, but then I can't access the stored credential. I'll export the credential into a file I guess, but thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I suspect that won't work either, the securestring would probably fail to be decrypted the minute you transfer it to a new machine.  You would need to encrypt your credentials on the target machine, as the user that's running the script, in order to be able to use it.  You could do a one off `Export-CliXml` or something on the target and save the file locally, and in the script `Import-CliXml`, but it's still hacky.

Comment: No other machine is involved though, just using one machine. Only difference is I "Sift + right click" "Run as a different user" which I guess is the same as running it on a different machine.